# How to fetch the result using TDengine python connector

Tags: python, tdengine

For the python connector of the TDengine database, I want to get the query result instead of knowing whether it was successfully executed or not. I just want to fetch the result, which api should I use?
I used `execute` before but it only returns `1` for success and other errors when failed.

Answer (score 0):

there are some examples in tdengine's githup repos, the links is https://github.com/taosdata/TDengine/tree/develop/tests/examples/python

```
   # query data and return data in the form of list
    try:
        c1.execute('select * from db.t')
    except Exception as err:
        conn.close()
        raise(err)

    # Column names are in c1.description list
    cols = c1.description
    # Use fetchall to fetch data in a list
    data = c1.fetchall()

    for col in data:
        print(col)

    print('Another query method ')

    try:
        c1.execute('select * from db.t')
    except Exception as err:
        conn.close()
        raise(err)

    # Use iterator to go through the retreived data
    for col in c1:
        print(col)

    conn.close()
```

I hope these can help you.